# HSQLDB issue: Using HSQL as backend for the existing MVC application using JDBC template

Tags: sql, spring-mvc, spring-security, hsqldb

I done my MVC web application using spring security 2.0.4 and spring 2.5 and HSQLDB, where I made CRUD application. For products I already used HSQL as a database. And I integrated security by using roles which are hard coded in my applicationContext-security.xml like this:

```
<authentication-provider>
            <user-service id="userDetailsService">
                    <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
                    <user name="username" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
                    <user name="test" password="test" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
```

Now I have to use same HSQL databse which I am using for products for the roles(Their user names and passwords). So I done the following cofigurations in my application:

My dataAccessContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <!-- business stuff below -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSourcePopulator" class="springapp1.service.HsqldbSchemaAndDataPopulator">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This is my dataSourcePopulator file: HsqldbSchemaAndDataPopulator.java

```
package springapp1.service;

    import javax.sql.DataSource;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.util.Assert;

    /**
     * I am responsible for populating the configured datasource
     */
    public class HsqldbSchemaAndDataPopulator implements InitializingBean {

        private JdbcTemplate template;

        /**
         *
         */
        public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
            Assert.notNull(template, "dataSource required");

            // add tables to represent admin core-domain instances.
            template
                    .execute("CREATE TABLE USERS(USERNAME VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
                            + "PASSWORD VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL,"
                            + "ENABLED BOOLEAN NOT NULL);");
            template
                    .execute("CREATE TABLE AUTHORITIES(USERNAME VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL,AUTHORITY VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT FK_AUTHORITIES_USERS FOREIGN KEY(USERNAME) REFERENCES USERS(USERNAME));");
            template
                    .execute("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IX_AUTH_USERNAME ON AUTHORITIES(USERNAME,AUTHORITY);");

            // add tables to represent bug tracking domain instances.
            // TODO - add project start and end date
            template
                    .execute("CREATE TABLE PROJECTS(ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, NAME VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(200) NOT NULL);");

            // insert data here
            template
                    .execute("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES('disabled','disabled',FALSE);");
            template.execute("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES('admin','admin',TRUE);");
            template
                    .execute("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES('username','password',TRUE);");
            template.execute("INSERT INTO USERS VALUES('test','test',TRUE);");

            template
                    .execute("INSERT INTO AUTHORITIES VALUES('admin','ROLE_USER');");
            template
                    .execute("INSERT INTO AUTHORITIES VALUES('admin','ROLE_ADMIN');");

            template
                    .execute("INSERT INTO AUTHORITIES VALUES('username','ROLE_USER');");

            template.execute("INSERT INTO AUTHORITIES VALUES('test','ROLE_USER');");

            template
                    .execute("INSERT INTO projects VALUES (1, 'Test Project', 'A description not longer than 200 chars of what project is.');");
            template
                    .execute("INSERT INTO projects VALUES (2, 'Test Project 2', 'Smaller description of project here.');");
        }

        public void setDataSource(final DataSource dataSource) {
            this.template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }
    }
```

My web.xml snippet:

```
<context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                      /WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml
                      /WEB-INF/dataAccessContext.xml
                      /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
                </param-value>
 </context-param>
```

I updated my applicationContext-security.xml file

```
<authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service id="userDetailsService" data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </authentication-provider>
```

Now when i run the application it gives me following error in localhost log file:

```
Mar 07, 2012 11:32:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Mar 07, 2012 11:33:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Mar 07, 2012 11:33:19 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'springapp1'
Mar 07, 2012 11:33:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet springapp1 threw exception
java.sql.SQLException: Table not found in statement [select id, description, price from products]
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingStatement.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:443)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:396)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:458)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:466)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.query(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:187)
    at springapp1.repository.JdbcProductDao.getProductList(JdbcProductDao.java:58)
    at springapp1.service.SimpleProductManager.getProducts(SimpleProductManager.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:106)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy34.getProducts(Unknown Source)
    at springapp1.web.InventoryController.handleRequest(InventoryController.java:32)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SessionFixationProtectionFilter.doFilterHttp(SessionFixationProtectionFilter.java:67)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.wrapper.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilterHttp(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.concurrent.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilterHttp(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
    at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

And its looking in the product list not in the users info list.

This is my Product DAO

```
 package springapp1.repository;

    import java.util.List;

    import springapp1.domain.Product;

    public interface ProductDao {

        public List<Product> getProductList();

        public void saveProduct(Product prod);

        public void deleteProduct(Product prod);

        public List<Product> retrieveProduct(int id);

        public Product createProduct(Product p);
    }
```

Implementation for DAO:

```
package springapp1.repository;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.ParameterizedRowMapper;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcDaoSupport;

import springapp1.domain.Product;

public class JdbcProductDao extends SimpleJdbcDaoSupport implements ProductDao {

    public void deleteProduct(Product prod) {
        logger.info("Deleting product with id: " + prod.getId());
        int count = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().update(
                "DELETE FROM products WHERE id = :id",
                new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("id", prod.getId()));
        logger.info(count + " rows were deleted");
    }

    public List<Product> retrieveProduct(int id) {
        List<Product> products = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(
                "select id, description, price from products where id = :id",
                new ProductMapper(),
                new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("id", id));
        if (products.size() == 0)
            return null;
        else
            products.get(id);
        return products;
    }

    public Product createProduct(Product p) {
        logger.info("Creating product: " + p.getDescription() + " Price:"
                + p.getPrice());

        int count = getSimpleJdbcTemplate()
                .update("INSERT INTO products (description,price,id) VALUES (:description, :price,:id)",
                        new MapSqlParameterSource()
                                .addValue("description", p.getDescription())
                                .addValue("price", p.getPrice())
                                .addValue("id", p.getId()));

        logger.info("Rows inserted: " + count);

        return p;
    }

    /** Logger for this class and subclasses */
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    public List<Product> getProductList() {
        logger.info("Getting products!");
        List<Product> products = getSimpleJdbcTemplate().query(
                "select id, description, price from products",
                new ProductMapper());
        return products;
    }

    public void saveProduct(Product prod) {
        logger.info("Saving product: " + prod.getDescription());
        int count = getSimpleJdbcTemplate()
                .update("update products set description = :description, price = :price where id = :id",
                        new MapSqlParameterSource()
                                .addValue("description", prod.getDescription())
                                .addValue("price", prod.getPrice())
                                .addValue("id", prod.getId()));
        logger.info("Rows affected: " + count);
    }

    private static class ProductMapper implements
            ParameterizedRowMapper<Product> {

        public Product mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Product prod = new Product();
            prod.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            prod.setDescription(rs.getString("description"));
            prod.setPrice(new Double(rs.getDouble("price")));
            return prod;
        }

    }

}
```

I am very confused and tried all things but of no use. Can any one help? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working !!

I have managed to work both (MVC application with security integration using database) using Spring 2.5, Spring security 2.0.4 and HSQLDB. What I have done here is that I have added in my dataSourcePopulator file: HsqldbSchemaAndDataPopulator.java following lines for the products to be populated:

```
template
.execute("CREATE TABLE USERS(USERNAME VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
+ "PASSWORD VARCHAR_IGNORECASE(50) NOT NULL,"
+ "ENABLED BOOLEAN NOT NULL);");
//some dummy items
template
.execute("INSERT INTO products (id, description, price) values(1, 'Lamp', 5.78);");
template
.execute("INSERT INTO products (id, description, price) values(2, 'Table', 75.29);");
template
.execute("INSERT INTO products (id, description, price) values(3, 'Chair', 22.81);");
```

And its working.